# Reload Data throwing unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

I seem to be experiencing a small error when dismissing a view and navigating back to a ViewController (with a UITableView)

**This is the code that loads the data into the tableView**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[getData getSavedTanks:^(NSArray *results) {
    self.array = results;
    [self.tankList reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@", results);

}];
}
```

The followup view in the stack is properly called, but when the view is dismissed, it seems as though the tableView has trouble reloading the data, and is throwing this error:

```
2014-04-28 21:15:57.698 ReefTrack[10205:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10be93210'
```

Not really sure how to handle this.  I'm having trouble understanding why reloadData is throwing an error.  I checked to see if there are any errant Segues pointing towards reload data but there doesn't appear to be.  Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: the error message is saying `self.tankList` is `PFObject` which does not have `reloadData` method

Comment: Strange because tankList is identified as a UITableView.  Not sure why this would occur.  What would you suggest for a fix?

Comment: find out how you create `self.tankList`

Comment: `self.tankList` is declared in the header file under a UITableView, in storyboard it's linked to a tableView w/ `tankList` being the referencing outlet.  The datasource and delegate are set to self.  The data loads fine when the view first appears but the above code pasted is the only time `reloadData` is called.

Comment: override `setTankList:` log all input

Comment: add method `-(void)setTankList:(id)val{NSLog(@"%@", val);_tankList = val;}` and run it again

Comment: Log: `2014-04-28 22:18:16.963 ReefTrack[10589:60b] <UITableView: 0x10d859400; frame = (0 243; 320 325); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10bd5acb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd2f190>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>`

Comment: @danh think you could take a look at this? I know we debugged the previous code together, and it seems as though the error is a result of that but I can't figure out where or why.

Comment: @BryanChen I can't see anything in the log here that refers to anything other than the creation of the tableView.  Am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure `[self.tankList reloadData];` is the line throw exception?

Comment: I put a break point at `[self.tankList reloadData];` and it crashed at that point.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",self.tankList);` before that line

Comment: `2014-04-29 00:33:55.874 ReefTrack[11023:60b] TANK LIST SELECTOR DEBUG: <SavedTanks:BaQ8SveOFz:(null)> {
    tankCapacity = "52 gallons";
    tankName = "Adding New Tank";
    userName = User;`

Comment: Adding to the complication; if I add a new object from a different view (Add Tank), and save it to the database, it correctly dismisses the view and has no trouble re-loading the data.  However, if I use the navigation bar to dismiss the view that's when I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

This was solved by placing the entire function in `viewDidLoad`.